# difference between 'static int' and 'int' in java

Tags: java

in java where and when do we use 'static int' and how does it differ from 'int'

Comment: You have failed to read any basic Java tutorials, right? Please do that now. http://www.google.com will help you find some.

Comment: @PrabuAnanthakrishnan as soon as you professionally pay my bill I’ll give you every answer you want. Until then somebody needs to learn how to use the internet.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look here: [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> When a number of objects are created from the same class blueprint, they each have their own distinct copies of `instance variables`. (...)
>
> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects. This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or `class variables`.

Answer (score 4):

The modifier *static* defines a variable as a class variable, meaning that there is exactly one of it only.
Without it, a variable is an instantiable variable, so this variable exist per Object.

For example:

```
class Test {
  static int i;
  int j;
}

class Test 2 {
   public static void main(String args[])  {
     Test test1 = new Test();
     Test test2 = new Test();
     test1.i = 1;
     test1.j = 2;
     test2.i = 3;
     test2.j = 4;
     System.out.println("test1.i: "+test1.i);
     System.out.println("test1.j: "+test1.j);
     System.out.println("test2.i: "+test2.i);
     System.out.println("test2.j: "+test2.j);
   }
}
```

If you create 2 objects of the *Test* class, both objects will "share" the *i* variable.
But each object will have its own *j* variable.

In the example above, the output will be

```
test1.i: 3
test1.j: 2
test2.i: 3
test2.j: 4
```

You can read more about it at [The Java Tutorials - Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 3):

Well.

It's used when declare member variables, and `static` refers to whether or not you need an **instance** of the given class to access it.

Typically, `static` is used for constants, or "helper" functions or variables. If you have too many, and if you end up combining static and non-static variables in a class, it ends up being suggestive of bad design (not all the time, though).

If a variable is `static`, it's value is shared between all usages (i.e. between all instances of the object). That is, if you change it, all other accesses will see the change.

A non-static variable will have a unique value per instance (as it can only be accessed *per* instance).

Comment: +1. Additionally, two class attributes declared in the same class, one of which is static, will be stored in different areas of the heap memory. The static attribute will be stored once in the "static" area (also known as "class" area) of the heap and is referenced by a single memory address. Therefore it is potentially shareable by all entities of the program (this depends on their access specifiers).
The non-static attribute will be allocated on the heap each time you create an object with the "new" operator, therefore it truly belongs to the object and is accessible through its address.

Answer (score 2):

`static` means it is not instance specific. It belongs to the `class`. Usually it goes with final.

```
public static final int MAX = 10000;  // Defined in MyClass

// Somewhere else you could do
int max = MyClass.MAX;  // notice no instance of MyClass needed.
```

EDIT :  It does not have to be final, non final variables are fine as long as one is careful.

Comment: please, can u explain...

Answer (score 1):

static int:
One variable per application
Can be accessed without object.

int:
One variable per object
Cannot be accessed without object.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'int' in a class means an integer field exists on each instance of the class. Using 'static int' means an integer field exists on the class (and not on each instance of the class)

Answer (score 0):

`static int`, which can be accessed directly without using objects.
`int`, which cannot be accessed directly without using objects.